# How to use subprocess.call to run a Windows program

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, psql

I'm trying to run a psql command in a Python script, with the subprocess command.
I use a Windows environment and the psql command aims to restore a database located in a remote Linux server.

The snippet is this one :

```
import os, sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call('psql -h ip_remote_server -p port -U user-d database -n schema --file="C:\Docs\script.sql"')
```

This does not work and the console tells that the specified file can't be found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks !

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use psycopg2?

Comment: Can you supply the complete traceback? We don't know if Python is having trouble finding `psql` or `"C:\Docs\script.sql"`. Also, you may have to use double backslashes as Python sees `"\D"` as `"D"`. So try `"C:\\Docs\\script.sql"`.

Comment: Actually, when I run a simple **subprocess.call('psql')** I have the same error message : WindowsError: [Error 2] specified file can't be found

Comment: You need to provide the path to `psql`. If you use backslashes, you will need to escape them (e.g. `"C:\\Program Files\\psql\\psql.exe"`).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your problem is definitely your paths. I went through the hassle of installing Python on Windows 10 and created these scripts:

**example.bat**

```
@echo off                                                                                                                                                                           
echo This is a stand-in for your program                                                                                                                                            
echo arg1 = %1                                                                                                                                                                      
echo arg2 = %2
```

**example.py**

```py
import subprocess                                                                                                                                                                   

subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\bogus\\example.bat example arguments")
```

**Console**

```
C:\Users\bogus>python example.py
This is a stand-in for your program                                                                                                                                                 
arg1 = example                                                                                                                                                                      
arg2 = arguments
```

As you can see, you do not need to pass `shell=True`, or split your command into a list.

If you look closely at the documentation for [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), you will see this (emphasis added):

> The arguments shown above are merely some common ones. **The full function signature is the same as that of the Popen constructor** - this function passes all supplied arguments other than timeout directly through to that interface.

If you look closely the documentation for [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), you will see this (emphasis added):

> **On Windows, if args is a sequence, it will be converted to a string** in a manner described in Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows. This is because the underlying CreateProcess() operates on strings.

Any advice about splitting your arguments into a list, or passing `shell=True`, only applies to POSIX, with one exception:

> The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.

Comment: Note that advice to not pass an argument list if `shell=True` still applies in Windows. `subprocess.list2cmdline` does not  quote and escape a command line correctly for the CMD shell in general. That would be difficult if not impossible.  Also the same applies if we run a .bat or .cmd script directly, since in that case `CreateProcessW` rewrites the command line to run `"%ComSpec%" /c` (i.e. `"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" /c`).

Comment: FYI, we can use a raw string for the command line string literal, instead of escaping backslashes. We can also use single quotes for the string literal, which makes it easier to quote paths with double quotes in the command line. For example: `r'"C:\Users\bogus\example.bat" example arguments'`.